# separating one character before the pattern in string

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to separate the pattern from the string along with the character which comes before and after it.

I have a string like this ihavehashasaahasabig which have a pattern of 3 "has" and I want to have one character before first "has" and one character after last "has".

Output should be like this.

ehashasaahasa

But when I used this code

```
String seq1="ihavehashasaahasabig";
    Pattern pat =Pattern.compile("\\w.has.*?has.*?has.\\w");
    Matcher m=pat.matcher(seq1);
    while (m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group());}
```

The output is like this:-
vehashasaahasab

Now what shall I do to solve my problem.

Comment: Remove the `\\w` from both the ends.

Comment: that's hard. unless you know every pattern ('has' is just one, how many more are there) you wont achieve it with regex alone. regex is like any other system, you have to tell it what to do. if you have an infinite number of possibilities, then it will be a headache to attempt. so i'd ask 'how many patterns do i have to match', if you cant answer that, then regex is not for your situation

Comment: @gwillie He just wants to match first `has` to last `has`. I don't how that is tough with regex.

Comment: agreed...but can 'has' be the only pattern? and its seems to be a she not a he

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify your regex to `.has.*?has.*?has.`

```
String seq1="ihavehashasaahasabig";
Pattern pat =Pattern.compile(".has.*?has.*?has.");
Matcher m=pat.matcher(seq1);
while (m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());}
```

**output**
ehashasaahasa

Answer (score 1):

You can use greedy quantifiers:

```
Pattern pat =Pattern.compile(".has.*has.");
```

With the greedy quantifier the *has* in the middle is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have one character before first "has"

You can use `String#replaceFirst(regex)`

```
str = str.replaceFirst("has", "e$0"));
```

> one character after last "has", use negative lookahead like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("has(?!.*?has)", "$0a"));
```

Comment: You are assuming that the character before and after are `e` and `a`.

Comment: No I am not assuming anything on my own :) OP wrote: `Output should be like this. ehashasaahasa` Those letters `e and a` are being used on RHS (replacement not search)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this as well:-

```
String seq1="ihavehashasaahasabig";
String seq1Rep= seq1.replaceAll("\[ihav\]");
String seq2Rep= seq1Rep.replaceAll("\[big\]");
System.out.println(seq2Rep);
```

Output:-This will replace only matching word in the string and you will get the desired output.